# How to fix a problem with installing fitdistrplus library?

Tags: r, linux

How to solve this error, please? Is there another package for this version?

```
install.packages("fitdistrplus"); library(fitdistrplus)
Installing package into ‘/home/linux/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘fitdistrplus’ is not available (for R version 3.4.4)
Error in library(fitdistrplus) : 
  there is no package called ‘fitdistrplus’
```

What I have done according to this [page][1]:

- I checked /etc/apt/sources.list

  #deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 19.2 *Tina* - Release amd64 20190729]/ bionic contrib main non-free

--> I do not have the line
--> I ran:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
[sudo] heslo pro linux:    
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.H9fjVZrS2l/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
gpg: klíč 51716619E084DAB9: „Michael Rutter <marutter@gmail.com>“ 1 nový podpis
gpg: Celkový počet zpracovaných klíčů: 1
gpg:         nové podpisy: 1
linux@linux-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/'
linux@linux-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt install r-base
Načítají se seznamy balíků… Hotovo
Vytváří se strom závislostí       
Načítají se stavové informace… Hotovo
r-base je již nejnovější verze (3.4.4-1ubuntu1).
Následující balíky byly nainstalovány automaticky a již nejsou potřeba:
  libllvm9 linux-headers-4.15.0-20 linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-128-generic linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-74-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-128-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-20-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-74-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-128-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-20-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-74-generic
Pro jejich odstranění použijte „sudo apt autoremove“.
0 aktualizováno, 0 nově instalováno, 0 k odstranění a 245 neaktualizováno.
linux@linux-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt install r-base
Načítají se seznamy balíků… Hotovo
Vytváří se strom závislostí       
Načítají se stavové informace… Hotovo
r-base je již nejnovější verze (3.4.4-1ubuntu1).
Následující balíky byly nainstalovány automaticky a již nejsou potřeba:
  libllvm9 linux-headers-4.15.0-20 linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-128-generic linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-74-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-128-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-20-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-74-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-128-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-20-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-74-generic
Pro jejich odstranění použijte „sudo apt autoremove“.
0 aktualizováno, 0 nově instalováno, 0 k odstranění a 245 neaktualizováno.
linux@linux-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$ r -- version

Příkaz 'r' nebyl nalezen, ale je možné jej nainstalovat pomocí:

sudo apt install r-cran-littler

linux@linux-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$ R --version
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) -- "Someone to Lean On"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under the terms of the
GNU General Public License versions 2 or 3.
For more information about these matters see
http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
```

The version is still 3.4.4

Answer (score 0):

According to this page:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fitdistrplus/index.html

the package works only for R version ≥ 3.5, you're on 3.4.

Could you update R to solve this? (links for this on the main R page https://cran.r-project.org/ )

Comment: I installed R last week and when I click HELP > CHECK FOR UPDATES, the table that I have the last version appears. I followed this commands: https://cran.r-project.org/ .

Comment: Try this: https://medium.com/@hpgomide/how-to-update-your-r-3-x-to-the-r-4-x-in-your-linux-ubuntu-46e2209409c3

Comment: I tried to follow this page and the version have not changed.